# Probability of busses arriving given 2 Poisson Processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Let the arrivals from Bus A be a Poisson process with rate 2/hr and the arrivals from Bus B be a Poisson process with 7/hr. Both processes are independent.

1) What is the probability that the first Bus A arrives before the first Bus B?

I think I solved this, just wanted to check if my method was right. So far, I calculated this to be $\frac{2}{9}$ given that $P(T_A<T_B)$ =$\int_{u=0}^\infty\int_{v=u}^\infty$$2e^{-2u}7e^{-7u}$=$\frac{2}{9}$.

2) If each bus breaks down independently with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ before reaching the stop, what is the probability that someone waits for 30 minutes without seeing a single bus?

So far, I separated this into 4 cases: 1) Both buses take more than 30 minutes without breaking down, 2) Bus A breaks down, Bus B takes more than 30 minutes without breaking down, 3) similar to scenario 2) but reversed, and 4) both busses break down.

I found the total probability to be: $e^{-2/2}e^{-7/2}$ + $\frac{1}{2}*e^{-7/2}$ + $\frac{1}{2}*e^{-2/2}$ +  $\frac{1}{2}$* $\frac{1}{2}$ $\approx$ $0.46$

Is this approach correct?

Comment: (1) Your equation seem incomplete and thus its numerical value is not verifiable. As I understand the problem, $T_A \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate}=2)$ and $T_B \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(\text{shape}=2, \text{rate}=7).$ By simulation, I get about 0.395 for the answer.

Comment: Also, 2/9 seems to be the probability that the first A arrives before the _first_ B. Then by the exponential no-memory property, I get $1 - (7/9)^2 \approx 0.395.$

Comment: @BruceET. My apologies, just edited the question -- should be the probability that the first A arrives before the first B. Also both arrivals are Poisson processes with rate $\lambda_A $ = 2 and $\lambda_B$ = 7. In other words $P(N_{A,B} = k)$ =$\frac{e^{-t*\lambda}*\lambda^k}{k!}$

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the reasoning in (1). For (2), I believe we can thin the Poisson process to obtain a new one $N_t$ with rate $0.5 * 9$, which is the process of buses arriving (i.e. the buses which *do not* break down). Note that I've merged the separate Poisson processes for each bus into one. Then we are asking for the probability that $N_{0.5} = 0$, which is just given by $$ \frac{(9/4)^{0} * e^{-9/4}}{(0!)} = e^{-9/4} \approx 0.11$$
since $N_{0.5}$ has distribution Poisson with rate $0.5 * (0.5 * 9)$.